# Store objects of a rooted hierarchy in a vector

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, invalidation

I have a [singly-rooted object hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singly_rooted_hierarchy) which each object has a pointer to its parent type. The root object is a move-only class (it has a move ctor and move assignment operator but no default ctor nor assignment). The problem is that I got invalidated pointers when the vector grows. Using a list instead is not a good solution for me.

I'm looking for any solutions to change current design.

Comment: It is not clear how you store the objects in the vector. Do you store the pointers or do you store the objects and then use their pointers?

Comment: @Veritas I'm storing the objects, not pointers to them.

Comment: This is tricky if you also care about caching. See my answer.

Comment: Can you store indices to parent object instead of pointers and update them accordingly before any vector modification? If this is often cache friendliness may not be worthy. Can you arrange the relationship between parent/child in a heap-like manner?

Comment: Polymorphic objects should be manipulated and stored by pointer or by reference only. Move-only, copy-only, no-copy-no-move that pertain to the objects themselves are all irrelevant. Your vector should only contain (smart) pointers which are pretty much copyable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the number of objects that you are going to store in advance, you can use the `std::vector::reserve` member function to ensure that memory won't be reallocated. This can also increase performance because it provides better locality of reference.

If you don't know the number of objects in advance, instead of storing the objects directly in the vector and using pointers to the objects afterwards, a better solution would be to store the actual pointers in the vector. This is a very good case for using `std::unique_ptr` since your vector owns the objects:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Object>> container;
std::unique_ptr<Object> object(new Object(/* */));
container.push_back(std::move(object));
```

As a last resort, instead of pointers you could use indices, achieving good locality of reference in the process. The problem with this approach is that you will also have to make the vector known to the caller that wants to access the objects.

Comment: Seem's there is no general way... Maybe something like a smart pointer hack